# Отобразить файл excel на страницу сайта Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть шаблон excel с форматированными ячейками (заголовки, объединённые ячейки, и прочее) я хочу загружать в этот шаблон свои данные и отображать на странице html, а затем и сохранить этот шаблон с данными. Какими способами это можно сделать. Смотрел библиотеки xlsx, sheetjs, react-doc-viewer (просит доступ к сайту microsoft), но такого не нашел. Может, где упустил что. Пишу на js. Или может есть парсер, который хорошо всё собирает в html. Спасибо.

Comment: Выглядит так, что вы хотите прикрутить базу данных без базы данных

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо! Решение найдено.
Это библиотека xlsx-viewer - отобразить эксель в том виде в каком есть.
А дальше уже через библиотеку xlsx открытие и сохранение